# Using jstree with XML and AJAX

Tags: xml, ajax, jstree

I'm trying to download an XML file with jstree and display it.
I'm using the syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tree").jstree({
            "xml_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Content/test.xml"
                },
                "xsl": "nest"
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "xml_data", "ui", "types"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, nothing is happening. I'm looking at the console and no request has been made. This is PRE 2.0.0 build from github. I've also tried version 1.0.0 Pre Fix 2 from official site, and that one does request but it's stuck on Loading... message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: I've managed to make it work with 1.0.0, 2.0.0 seems to be broken at the moment. Thank you anyway for the interest.

Comment: You can always share how you did it ...

Comment: I used the code from the above, it works with 1.0.0 (I thought it doesn't, but I had issue of other sort).